# Arrange dataframe for pairwise correlations

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I am working with data in the following form:

```
Country   Player    Goals
"USA"     "Tim"     0
"USA"     "Tim"     0
"USA"     "Dempsey" 3
"USA"     "Dempsey" 5
"Brasil"  "Neymar"  6
"Brasil"  "Neymar"  2
"Brasil"  "Hulk"    5
"Brasil"  "Luiz"    2
"England" "Rooney"  4
"England" "Stewart" 2
```

Each row represents the number of goals that a player scored per game, and also contains that player's country. I would like to have the data in the form such that I can run pairwise correlations to see whether being from the same country has some association with the number of goals that a player scores. The data would look like this:

```
Player_1 Player_2
0        8 # Tim     Dempsey
8        5 # Neymar  Hulk
8        2 # Neymar  Luiz
5        2 # Hulk    Luiz
4        2 # Rooney  Stewart
```

(You can ignore the comments, they are there simply to clarify what each row contains).

How would I do this?

```
table(df$player)
```

gets me the number of goals per player, but then how to I generate these pairwise combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty classic self-join problem. I'm gonna start by summarizing your data to get the total goals for each player. I like `dplyr` for this, but aggregate or `data.table` work just fine too.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(Player, Country) %>% dplyr::summarize(Goals = sum(Goals)) 

> df
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: Player

   Player Country Goals
1 Dempsey     USA     8
2    Hulk  Brasil     5
3    Luiz  Brasil     2
4  Neymar  Brasil     8
5  Rooney England     4
6 Stewart England     2
7     Tim     USA     0
```

Then, using good old merge, we join it to itself based on country, and then so we don't get each row twice (Dempsey, Tim and Tim, Dempsey---not to mention Dempsey, Dempsey), we'll subset it so that `Player.x` is alphabetically before `Player.y`. Since I already loaded `dplyr` I'll use `filter`, but `subset` would do the same thing.

```
df2 <- merge(df, df, by.x = "Country", by.y = "Country")
df2 <- filter(df2, as.character(Player.x) < as.character(Player.y))

> df2
   Country Player.x Goals.x Player.y Goals.y
2   Brasil     Hulk       5     Luiz       2
3   Brasil     Hulk       5   Neymar       8
6   Brasil     Luiz       2   Neymar       8
11 England   Rooney       4  Stewart       2
15     USA  Dempsey       8      Tim       0
```

The self-join could be done in `dplyr` if we made a little copy of the data and renamed the `Player` and `Goals` columns so they wouldn't be joined on. Since `merge` is pretty smart about the renaming, it's easier in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a smarter way to get from the aggregated data to the pairs, but assuming your data is not too big (national soccer data), you can always do something like:

```
A<-aggregate(df$Goals~df$Player+df$Country,data=df,sum)
players_in_c<-table(A[,2])
dat<-NULL
for(i in levels(df$Country)) {
    count<-players_in_c[i]
    pair<-combn(count,m=2)
    B<-A[A[,2]==i,]
    dat<-rbind(dat, cbind(B[pair[1,],],B[pair[2,],]) )
}
dat

> dat
    df$Player df$Country df$Goals df$Player df$Country df$Goals
1        Hulk     Brasil        5      Luiz     Brasil        2
1.1      Hulk     Brasil        5    Neymar     Brasil        8
2        Luiz     Brasil        2    Neymar     Brasil        8
4      Rooney    England        4   Stewart    England        2
6     Dempsey        USA        8       Tim        USA        0
```